# How to give drag selected cell count to colspan value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have Dynamic a dynamic table here. I am trying to give drag selected cell count as colspan value to the selected table cells(merge).my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/q35vm6qv/6/

```
$(document).mouseup(function () {
isMouseDown = false;
mylength = $("td.highlighted").length;
//alert(mylength);
});    
$("#mergeme").live('click', function () {
$("td.highlighted").attr("colspan"+ mylength);
alert("colspan" + mylength);
});
```

Comment: **Note:** [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9 consider updating your jQuery and use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change this:

```
$("#mergeme").live('click', function () {
$("td.highlighted").attr("colspan"+ mylength);
alert("colspan" + mylength);
});
```

for this:

```
    $("#mergeme").click(function () {
        var mylength = $(".highlighted").length;

        // Add the colspan of already merged columns
        $(".highlighted").each(function(index,el){
            if($(el).attr("colspan")>1)
                mylength += $(this).attr("colspan") - 1;
        });

        // Get text from highlighted cells
        var alltext = $(".highlighted").text();

        // Hide non-first highlighted cells
        $("td.highlighted:not(:first)")
            .hide()
            .toggleClass("highlighted");

        // Set text to first highlighted cell, unhighlight, and set colspan
        $("td.highlighted:first").attr("colspan", mylength)
            .text(alltext)
            .toggleClass("highlighted");
      });
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/9ep1gsr8/1/

Note: you should limit your selection to cells of the same row, or the merge will be a mess.

Comment: how can i prevent vertical drag selection?

Comment: on mousedown you could store in which row have you clicked, and compare with this value when highlighting other cells

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
$(document).mouseup(function () {
isMouseDown = false;
mylength = $("td.highlighted").length;
//alert(mylength);
});    
$("body").on('click','#mergeme', function () {
$("td.highlighted").attr("colspan", mylength);
alert("colspan" + mylength);
});
```